# how to disable input entry validation in asp.net web forms

Tags: asp.net, validation

I need to show some html code in TextBox.
this is my TextBox description:

`<asp:TextBox ID="responseTextBox" runat="server" 
        Width="910px" ReadOnly="True" TextMode="MultiLine" CausesValidation="false" />`

i am passing the html to it programatically, and it works, but on postback from page i'am getting the following error:

A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$MainContent$responseTextBox=" ...

How can i disable input validation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

asp.net imposes this checking to avoid script injections.But you can override this by changing the validateRequest property value to "false" in page directive

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="editpage.aspx.cs" validateRequest="false" Inherits="MyProject.UI.editpage" %>
```

[Check here to know more about Script injection](http://aspalliance.com/1648_Understanding_Script_Injection_Attacks.all)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the validaterequest=false attribute, but I would not recommend doing this. Encode/decode the HTML instead.

http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/11/01/ASPNET-Data-Input-Validation.aspx